# breakpoints do not work if in another script file - Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, ide, breakpoints

I divided my Google Script into few script files. Now I want to use a breakpoint that is in a script file that is called from another script file that is called from the very first file. Such breakpoint is not ever used. Only the ones on the very first level.

[image]

I want to use the breakpoint in `parsers.gs` in a function that is called from `email func.gs` and it is being called from the very first `parse emails.gs`.

Is there any way how to debug functions in `parsers.gs` file?

Comment: There's a new ide incoming now. Perhaps that'll solve the issue?

Comment: otherwise there is no way to "solve" this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [TheMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8404453/themaster) has suggested, I can confirm that this has been fixed in the new editor:

[image]

If you do not have the new editor rolled out to you, then unfortunately you will have to copy the function into the first level of scripts and insert breakpoints.

I would normally suggest *filing a feature request* with Google on their Issue Tracker to suggest implementation, but as this seems to be fixed in the new editor it will likely not be seen to now.

#### References:

- [Release Notes - December 7, 2020 | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases#december_7_2020)

Comment: You will see it - once you get it it's default, and to go back you click the `Use legacy editor` button. Unfortunately until then, you will just have to wait :/

Comment: how did you create the video gif?

Comment: @Radek [Screenify](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screencastify-screen-vide/mmeijimgabbpbgpdklnllpncmdofkcpn) to record, [ezgif](https://ezgif.com/crop) to crop to relevant area.